# How to initialize a div width and change automatically after put some content in it in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`, I want to initialize a width, for example, `100px` after putting some content it should automatically change the width. Is it possible in pure CSS? or should I use JavaScript?

```
<div></div>

<style>

div{
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

<style>
```

I already use min-width it does not works, It makes it 100% width. 

Advance Thanks

Comment: add display:inline-block

Answer (score 0):

CSS is enough to achieve that.
What you're missing is `display: inline-block;`.

```css
div {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```